# An article for some undergraduate journal

Tags: soft-question, publishing, article-writing

I'm a student and last year I attended some courses about algebraic geometry. Referring to many books, I wrote  personal notes explaining the Cech cohomology of sheaves and some of its applications in algebraic geometry. I gave these notes to other students as well as some professors. All were very enthusiastic about what I wrote, and said that my notes are clear and very useful to learn the subject.
Now, if I want to make my work known (considering that it was so appreciated), is it possible to turn my  brief notes into an article for an undergraduate journal? Are there any journals that accept these kinds of articles?

Comment: Usually people publish such notes on their personal web page or blog.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You should try *[Involve, a Journal of Mathematics](http://msp.org/involve/about/cover/cover.html)*. I published an article with the journal as an undergraduate, and I can vouch for the efficiency and quality of its reviewing process, which are really fantastic. The editors are well-known mathematicians as well. All the best for your article!

Comment: Doesn't this journal publish original research only?  It says: "All manuscripts accepted for publication in Involve are considered publishable in quality journals in their respective fields" on their site.

Comment: Yes, of course. I’m assuming that the OP has a new perspective of the material that others would consider *novel*. :)